# What is the signs that a lonely kitty is abandoned by the mother

Tags: cats, health, strays

Today I found a small kitty in my garden with no mother in sight, so me and my brother decided to feed it, then we waited patiently for the mother. This is actually my first time, yet the little one warmed it's way to my heart in a flash. The mother didn't came at all during the day and the the little poor one is now sleeping the night on the below outside and it is breaking my heart. Yet it never cried loudly for it's mother nor it seemed to be in distress.

I suspected a big cat that came near it to be the mother, but there wasn't any interaction that I can tell from and the only thing it does is eating from the kitty's food or water. But the kitty didn't mind nor was afraid of it. So how could I tell if it's abandoned?

I'm really freaking out: I have an exam in less than 9 hours, but all in my mind is little kitty that I know mother won't allow inside and will kick it outside the garden soon. And what does make it worse is that there is no local vet or any animal caring center around me.

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Are you needing to know signs to look for to determine if it's too young to be detached from its mother? Or what's the difference between a weaned kitten or one that still needs to nurse? Or do you need advice on what to do from here?     -what type of food did it eat (was it kibble dry food, canned cat food, tuna or chicken from your house, etc...)? How big was it, and can you describe size by comparing it to the size of something, or add a pic?

Comment: Um sorry I was so freaked out when I wrote...it's just I'm so worried I just want to know if the mother detached it or not ...it's so hungry I just gave her chicken & it jumped on it immediately ...is it okay I also want to know how to help it to care for herself as my mother won't allow me to keep it..I will add a picture

Comment: @ChristyB.  I reckon the kitten looks about 6 weeks old. What do you think?  A photo of the kitten being held would be good, or next to an adult sized hand to give a frame of reference

Comment: @YvetteColomb, yeah, about 6 weeks give or take.

Comment: @ChristyB. yeh, she doesn't sound like she's in good shape. It's an unfortunate situation and I really feel for both the kitten and the OP. :/  I think it would be good to discuss this type of distress in meta at some point.

Comment: @YvetteColomb, good idea! I notice eye crusties on her too. Poor little baby, unfortunate she doesn't have a vet or rescue close by.

Comment: Can't I save her? Please, ask some vet & tell them the situation they probably can help her she is my first I won't give her up yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the kitten is alone for a day like that, then the kitten is essentially "abandoned",  or is lost or homeless. Many things may have happened. The mother may have been trapped and taken. The kitten may have been dumped. It's unlikely the kitten would be naturally away from it's mother by choice, being so small.

The kitten definitely needs care. Food, fresh water, shelter and protection from predators. If your mother won't provide that and there's no one shelters, it's difficult to know what to advise.

You say you have an exam. I don't know if you're at school, or a higher college or university, you could always put up a notice for someone willing to take the kitten. Negotiate with your mother, that you could look after her until you find her a home. Or take it to school and see if there's a responsible adult who will take it.

If your mother won't let her into the house, then provide a box with a towel in a sheltered area, with a bowl of water and food. This kitten will need to be fed before you leave, when you return and before you go to bed. Preferably, it would be good to lay down some kitten dry food for  the in between times for her to snack. Being outdoors, without supervision, it's more than likely that any food left out for her will be eaten by other animals.

If there is any local vet arrange to have the kitten taken to the local vet. At least they can care for it.

Just be warned, the kitten is vulnerable outside and at a high risk of poor health or dying without protection and care. She will need to be wormed and vaccinated and is prey to dogs and any other local native carnivores, including birds. She has not eaten enough in the last day at the very least and if not taken care of could also starve to death. The longer she goes without the proper care, medicine, nutrition the less chance she has of surviving.

Try and convince your mother to take the burden of responsibility of making this kitten safe. Good luck and let us know how you get on.

Update: from [your comment](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/what-is-the-signs-that-a-lonely-kitty-is-abandoned-by-the-mother/17281?noredirect=1#comment22288_17281).

> about her size she's three times my palm size,today I gave her some
>   tuna & water..she didn't drink enough water considering how hot today
>   is,also noticed that she can't see me completely & her eyes are blurry
>   ( respiratory infection?)she is walking slower.

This kitten needs urgent Veterinary care. She is sick and will die without medical treatment. You haven't done anything wrong, she would be worse off if you hadn't fed and watered her.

She needs to be taken to a Vet immediately. She is very young and sick. She is deteriorating and will die without seeing a Veterinarian. I'll repeat, the longer she goes without the proper care, medicine, nutrition the less chance she has of surviving.

Comment: Yes I figured that out now.The fact there is nothing I can do breaks my heart, my friend found a page on facebook for animal care so I put her to adoption..I'm 21 years old I think I'm adult now but a hopeless one..about her size she's three times my palm size,today I gave her some tuna & water..she didn't drink enough water considering how hot today is,also noticed that she can't see me completely & her eyes are blurry ( respiratory infection?)she is walking slower.Did I starve her or did something wrong,I hope she survives until I find her a home or help my mom has phobia so I can't do it

Comment: @Alice where are you located? I will search for help. This kitten needs urgent Veterinary treatment. Is there any way she can be taken to a vet? 
Please don't put yourself down as being a hopeless 21 yo, you have a kind heart and that's the most important thing in life. You have bothered to help her and seek help of how to best do it.

Comment: Did I poisoned her ! We are currently staying in Jordan because of my father job , I tried to call animal care center I just found but they won't pick up, is she dying? Please tell there is something I can do by myself, I begged my mother to help me but she won't listen. Please please what should I do?!

Comment: @Alice you did not poison her. She needs to be taken to a Vet immediately. She is very young and sick. She is deteriorating and will die without seeing a Veterinarian. The longer she goes without the proper care, medicine, nutrition the less chance she has of surviving.

Comment: I don't want her to die its not fair that this country don't care for animals or that my family are bunch of heartless humans no one want to help & the only vent is far away from here, my tears only got me mocked by them & mother banned me from see her, she is so small and needs her mom this is so painful I can't handle it..please I beg all if you what sould I do to save her

Comment: @Alice https://www.four-paws.org.au/projects/stray-animals/rest-of-the-world-stray-animal-care/stray-animal-care-jordan/  http://www.hcaw-jordan.org/  http://www.sbs.com.au/topics/life/culture/article/2016/12/05/one-animal-hospital-saving-jordans-forgotten-pets It sounds like you're in a culture that has a reasonably large proportion of people disregarding strays

Comment: @Alice she's hungry, at the very least she needs kitten food. It would be best if she could get Vet care. I really feel for you, as  I can hear your pain and distress and I am on the other side of the world. I want to give you a big hug (I'm a 49 year old woman - with children your age) and tell you, I'd be proud to have you as my daughter, caring so much for this small life. I don't know if you have access to a car, or someone who can drive and get her to a shelter? At the very least some food and a hiding place - some type of box she can shelter in. This is a terrible situation. Upsetting!

Comment: She's fine now!!! I thought I would find a dead kitten this morning but gladly she's back to her hyper curious  precious self ..I'm so happy crying & laughing at the same time, she has clear eyes today jumping around and into food eagerly,she is so strong & willing to survive she taught me a lot in just 3 days, so I won't let her down ..I secretly fed her 2 egg yolks (does she need more?) & fresh water but didn't seem thirsty,both of us still timid around each other I will try my best to overcome this inherited fear and be more involved

Comment: And really I appreciate what you've said to me yesterday my mother see what I'm doing to be stupid and childish ..I can't drive yet or I would have sneaked her to the vet already..never someone said they would be proud of me before,you don't know how happy I'm to hear that, I'm really really thankful

Comment: @Alice I'm so glad to hear that she is perky and also glad to have given you something. It saddens me to hear that you haven't had that before. Try and get some kitten food, go easy on the eggs, not too many, but any meat (even if it's some egg yolks) that you can give her is better than not eating. She may not drink a lot of water and that can be normal. They tend to drink more water when eating dry food. Keep up the good work, lots of feeds, a protected little shelter and keep us posted with any new questions. You're doing well :) I wish you had the support of those around you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help your a marvellous  mother <3 I'll try my best to protect her until she can be strong & big ...I named her cheshire because of her ability to disappear & reappear in the blink of an eye ^^ my friend was amused about this Alice & Cheshire (lol) I hope I can find a mad hatter also XD ,thanks again everyone we'll take a step at time & survive :)

Comment: @Alice you're welcome and all the best :)